# Why Apache Velocity cannot handle multiple dot keys

Tags: java, velocity

I dont get this while using Apache Velocity 1.7.
When I have a vm like this

```
db.connection.url = $db.customer.environment.db_url
```

and a context like this...

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("db.customer.environment.db_url", "//sample_db_conn");
```

I am getting this error

Caused by: org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Object 'java.lang.String' does not contain property 'environment' at db.properties.vm[line 2, column 42]

But if I put it like this.. it works...

```
context.put("db.db_url", "//sample_db_conn");
```

Not sure why having multiple "." in the context key is causing this error.
Any hints how to get over this?

Comment: Please give me a full stack trace of exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot is used as a property accessor. When Velocity sees `$db.customer.environment.db_url`, it will try to get an object from the context under the `db` key, then try to call `getCustomer()` or `get("customer")` on it, and so on.

So using dots in keys is a pretty bad idea with Velocity - yet, there are some workarounds.

You need to put the context in itself, with something like:

```
context.put("context", context);
```

and then in your template you will be able to do:

```
$context.get("db.customer.environment.db_url")
```